# com_facebook_android.apk

Tags: facebook-android-sdk

I understand com_facebook_android.apk is designed to install on an emulator (which doesn't have the full blown Facebook app) in order to allow testing.

I've run across a situation where someone running my app does not have Facebook already installed on their phone.  Is it reasonable to bundle com_facebook_android.apk with my app so, regardless of what's installed, I can guarantee I my app has Facebook access?

Or is com_facebook_android.apk a testing only kind of thing?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We include the APK solely for developers to test native SSO (authenticating your app via Facebook for Android).  If the user does not have the native Facebook app installed, a WebView pops up and they are prompted to log in via that window.

Do not bundle the Facebook APK with your app, it is only used for you to test that your configurations are correct for native SSO to work.

Comment: Ok.  That's what I thought but figured it wouldn't hurt to double check.